# Library to extract phrasal verbs from English texts

Tags: language-agnostic, nlp, linguistics

Is there any library for auto detection of phrasal (compound) verbs in English texts? And maybe other kinds of word groups that form a special meaning?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a library for that. However, you might find this article useful. It discusses using n-gram (Markvov) models and statistical methods (such as SVM) to detect not only phrasal verbs, but also other phrasal terms.

[[[http://seer.lcc.ufmg.br/index.php/jidm/article/viewFile/79/39]]](http://seer.lcc.ufmg.br/index.php/jidm/article/viewFile/79/39%5d%5d)

"Using Statistical Features to Find Phrasal Terms in Text Collections".
André Luiz da Costa Carvalho, Edleno Silva de Moura, Pável Calado.
Journal of Information and Data Management 1(3), October 2010: 583–597.